# take first characters of edittext

Tags: java, android

i have today an computer program who works with codes,
these codes are entered by the user
now i am busy working on an android App to do the same thing as the computer program.
these codes are so common in our company in the mean while that i cant get around them anymore.

codes look like W07 or START12345,00
the W and the START show what kind of action the program has to take

as the user puts his codes in an edittext box i want to take the first letters of his input to define the action after it.
how can i perform this action?

Comment: could you have two differents EditText, once for the command code the other for the number part

Comment: nope, not possible, because the edittextbox can be filled out by a scanner-barcode also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char c  : editText.getText().toString().toCharArray())
    if (Character.isLetter(c))
        result.append(c);
    else break;

String code = result.toString();
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, i go puzzle a bit whit this one, the difficult part will be that there are also characters where no special action need to be done

Comment: i get in trouble with the statement "result"

Comment: result is 2 times red underlined making an variable of it (string) doesnt work either

Comment: Do you have result variable declared early? Try to compile and provide me error text

Comment: "contains errors" is only error text, what type should the result variable be? string doesn't work

Comment: It should be StringBuilder

Comment: was my fault, changed the first result expression to my variables, thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
String yourcode=editText.getText().toString();
String yourcode2=yourcode;
yourcode2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "x");
int index=yourcode2.lastIndexOf("x");
preyourcode=yourcode.substring(0, index+1);
code=yourcode.substring(index+1,yourcode.length());
```

Comment: first line gives error, "cannot convert from edittext to string

Answer (score 0):

Use `Java.lang.String.contains()` method

[Java.lang.String.contains() description](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm)